# Reducing memory of NSString in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have used few functions in my app.In each function there are some local String variable.My functions are called multiple times eg.100 function example

```
 -(void)getData
    {
        if(result==1)
        {
             NSString *componentid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentid];
                        NSString *componentsubclientid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentsubclientid];
                        NSString *componentClientid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentClientid];
                        NSString *componentEntityid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentEntityid];
                        NSString *componentWorkorderid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentWorkorderid];
                        NSString *componentStatus=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)subcomponent.componentStatus];
                        NSString *notes=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentNotes];
                        NSString *componentAllImages=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentAllImages];
                        NSString *componentAllImagesTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subcomponent.componentAllImagesTime];

//after some code 

 componentinspectionid=nil;
                    inspectorid=nil;
                    componentid=nil;
                    componentsubclientid=nil;
                    componentClientid=nil;
                    componentEntityid=nil;
                    componentWorkorderid=nil;
                    componentStatus=nil;
                    notes=nil;
                    componentAllImages=nil;
                    componentAllImagesTime=nil;

        } 



    }
```

Please guide me.`Will above code increase the memory ?`If yes then what is best solution for writing the code so that memory does not increase.

Comment: you have to use NSobject Class insted of many NSString .

Comment: I don't think the memory will increase. ARC should free the memory when you set the values to nil.

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat` instead of a straight string assignment?

Answer (score 1):

No your code not seems that it will increase memory. and second thing `ARC` automatically clear local variables or references after use. so, there no possibility of memory issue according to me. Hope this will help :)